# HttpInterceptor Angular Js

Tags: angularjs

Here is my code for httpinterceptor, basically I want to intercept all http calls and append token the request. I followed this [post](https://auth0.com/blog/2014/01/07/angularjs-authentication-with-cookies-vs-token/)

What am I doing wrong here?

```
   angular.module('app', []).factory('authInterceptor', function ($rootScope, $q, $window) {
    return {
        request: function (config) {
            config.headers = config.headers || {};
            if ($window.sessionStorage.token) {
                config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + $window.sessionStorage.token;
            }
            return config;
        },
        response: function (response) {
            if (response.status === 401) {
                // handle the case where the user is not authenticated
            }
            return response || $q.when(response);
        }
    };
}).config(function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('authInterceptor');
});
```

I get a error

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: commonProvider <- common
```

Comment: On first glance your code looks ok. Are you injecting `commonProvider` anywhere else in your code?

Comment: @MattWay - No I dont inject commonProvider anywhere in my code.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle with your code then?

Comment: Using any third-party libraries?

Comment: Have you checked the stack trace to verify if the error indeed is coming from this piece of code?

Comment: @MattWay - It works fine when I create Plunker with just that authInterceptor. It throws error only when I use in my existing application. Any wild guess what should I check in my application

Comment: Do you have anything named `common`, and if yes, how are you using it?

Comment: Do a project wide search for `common`?

Comment: I do have a module named 'common'. let me rename and see if the error still exists

Comment: What version of Angular are you using? The approach is different depending on your version.

Comment: @eddiec - I use v1.2.12

Comment: Are you trying to inject the `common` module somewhere, for example in a controller or a factory?

Comment: thanks everyone i added the solution in the answer section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my config.js file I have

```
app.config(['commonConfigProvider', function (cfg) {

    }]);
```

which is called before the authInterceptor.
I moved the authInterceptor before the commonConfigProvider and now works fine. Not sure Why!